# generate_series : how to remove or no generate the last one

Tags: postgresql

I use this function for generating time slots. It's work well. But, there is a little problem.

My business opens at 10:00 and close at 12:00.

-- generate slots

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION slots(start_date TIMESTAMP, end_date TIMESTAMP, delay INTERVAL) RETURNS SETOF TIMESTAMP AS $$
BEGIN
RETURN QUERY SELECT * FROM generate_series(start_date::timestamp, end_date, delay);
END
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

-- call the function

```
SELECT slots('2019-12-19 10:00', '2019-12-19 12:00', '30 mins')
```

-- Results

```
2019-12-19 10:00:00
2019-12-19 10:30:00
2019-12-19 11:00:00
2019-12-19 11:30:00
2019-12-19 12:00:00
```

As you can see, the last generated slot is not available, because of my business close at 12:00. How can i remove or not generate this one?

Answer (score 2):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION slots(start_date TIMESTAMP, end_date TIMESTAMP, delay INTERVAL) RETURNS SETOF TIMESTAMP AS $$
BEGIN
RETURN QUERY SELECT * FROM generate_series(start_date, end_date - delay, delay);
END
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Last timeslot is not generated even it is partial (not empty at all) - i.e.

```
SELECT slots('2019-12-19 10:00', '2019-12-19 12:10', '30 mins')
```

will not generate `'2019-12-19 12:00'` timeslot because it has 10 mins length.

If such partial timeslot must be generated, then substract `'1 second'::interval` instead of `delay` from `end_date`.

Comment: Thank Akina :) Works well!